# I changed my github username. How do I update local repository to point to the new location?

Tags: git, github, repository

I'm really new to github and don't know very much. I changed my username to be a easier to find for people that know me or meet me. It tells me to update my local repositories to point to the new location. I don't know how to do this or how to find my old url and new url? Is there any way to find step by step what I need to do? I've found a few sources to learn github and git but those are lengthy. I plan to go through them to understand this more for the future but for now I want to change this so I can continue to work on my projects without worrying something messing up when I push to github. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

If your old username was XYZ, and your new one Jakeunderscore, then your old Github account would have been found at `https://github.com/XYZ`, and your new one, `https://github.com/Jakeunderscore`. So, for each repository that you have that has a remote pointing to Github, simply run the following command:

`git remote set-url origin https://github.com/Jakeunderscore/repo_name.git`

where repo_name represents the name of the current repository. Of course, this is assuming that you created a remote `origin` that pointed to your old repository link `https://github.com/XYZ/repo_name.git`

**Update, addressing the comment:**

If you created via the Github app, then it ought to have created an origin for you. To check, go to that folder, and type `git remote -v`. If you see `origin` (or 2 `origin`s, its alright), then the command I posted ought to work. To check if it does actually work, try pulling from the repository with a `git pull origin master`, and you ought to get a message like `Already up-to-date`. Or, if you have unpushed commits in your repo, push to the repository with a `git push origin master`, and if it shows that everything is pushed without an error, you're good to go.

If, by chance, you don't have origin already created, create it with the command `git remote add origin https://github.com/Jakeunderscore/repo_name.git`.

Comment: How do I know if I created a remote origin that pointed to my old repository link? The way I created the repository prior to changing my name was by just using the github application, going to file new repository then pushing my new repository to github. Do I need to just go the my repository directory on my computer and type in the command you posted with the appropriate names? And how will I know if it worked?

Comment: @Jakeunderscore : Sorry, didn't see your comment before. I've updated the answer now.

Comment: Shouldn't this be the accepted answer? It worked for me as well

Comment: @zltn.guba yes, it should be accepted as answer! This is such great explanation